# ssh tunnel stopped working

Tags: linux, ssh

Suddenly my call to ssh -f -vvv rdp@corn06.stanford.edu -L 2025:corn06.stanford.edu:55576 -N stopped working. It prints the output at the bottom of this post, and then the process terminates. Yet it seems to properly set up the listener, because when I rerun the command, it says:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 2025
Could not request local forwarding.
```

Do I need to sort out an issue with RSA keys?

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 3: Applying options for *.stanford.edu
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 6: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to corn06.stanford.edu [171.67.216.71] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/afs/ir/users/r/d/rdp/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /afs/ir/users/r/d/rdp/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /afs/ir/users/r/d/rdp/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/ir/users/r/d/rdp/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/ir/users/r/d/rdp/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/ir/users/r/d/rdp/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /afs/ir/users/r/d/rdp/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 171.67.216.71.
debug1: Offering GSSAPI proposal: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-gex-sha1-A/vxljAEU54gt9a48EiANQ==,gss-group1-sha1-A/vxljAEU54gt9a48EiANQ==,gss-group14-sha1-A/vxljAEU54gt9a48EiANQ==,gss-gex-sha1-bontcUwnM6aGfWCP21alxQ==,gss-group1-sha1-bontcUwnM6aGfWCP21alxQ==,gss-group14-sha1-bontcUwnM6aGfWCP21alxQ==,gss-gex-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==,gss-group1-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==,gss-group14-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "corn06.stanford.edu" from file "/afs/ir/users/r/d/rdp/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "corn06.stanford.edu" from file "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-gex-sha1-A/vxljAEU54gt9a48EiANQ==,gss-group1-sha1-A/vxljAEU54gt9a48EiANQ==,gss-group14-sha1-A/vxljAEU54gt9a48EiANQ==,gss-gex-sha1-bontcUwnM6aGfWCP21alxQ==,gss-group1-sha1-bontcUwnM6aGfWCP21alxQ==,gss-group14-sha1-bontcUwnM6aGfWCP21alxQ==,gss-gex-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==,gss-group1-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==,gss-group14-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss,null
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: Doing group exchange

debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 131/256
debug2: bits set: 518/1024
debug1: Calling gss_init_sec_context
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: Received GSSAPI_COMPLETE
debug1: Calling gss_init_sec_context
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug2: bits set: 505/1024
debug1: Rekey has happened - updating saved versions
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /afs/ir/users/r/d/rdp/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f4afc2faf20)
debug2: key: /afs/ir/users/r/d/rdp/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /afs/ir/users/r/d/rdp/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug2: we sent a gssapi-keyex packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (gssapi-keyex).
Authenticated to corn06.stanford.edu ([171.67.216.71]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:2025 forwarded to remote address corn06.stanford.edu:55576
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 2025.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 2025.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

Comment: Sounds like it's doing what you ask. You are combining -f (fork) with -N (execute no command), so ssh forks a background process and leaves your terminal free to do other work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out port 2025 was in use by another session. I just needed to use a different port number.